# Flickr upload by email to Tumblr

Tags: email, tumblr, flickr

Is it possible to upload an image to Tumblr over Flickr by email feature?
It looks like Flickr is offering that but it's not working for me: 
(Login required)
http://www.flickr.com/blogs.gne

Answer (score 2):

It [seems](http://www.flickr.com/help/forum/en-us/72157626934175020/72157626944694559/) Flickr does not have email support for Tumblr, yet as described by a staff member 7 months ago:

> Although, we currently do not support posting to Tumblr blogs via upload by e-mail, you can submit your idea for improvement or feature request to Flickr ideas:
>
> www.flickr.com/groups/flickrideas/

I have browsed the topic and have not seen the idea listed so maybe consider submitting the idea.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, consider using [ifttt](http://ifttt.com). There are already quite a few recipes for posting [flickr photos to tumblr](http://ifttt.com/recipes/search?q=flickr%20tumblr)